# Implementation for cloud storage services in Android

Tags: android, interface, cloud, dropbox, google-drive-api

Does anyone know an open source app that uses several different cloud storage services (like Drive, Dropbox etc.)? I want to implement file synchronization into my Android app with an "interface" to easily switch and add cloud storage services. Any ideas? Otherwise I would have to start from scratch.

Comment: In case you start from scratch, here is a starting point regarding Dropbox Sync API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948156/dropbox-sync-api-android-updating-cached-files/20951592#20951592

Comment: Cloud services are very different and having a universal layer is almost impossible - such layer will be very feature-limited. We have cloud client components in our SecureBlackbox product, and they attempt to deliver such layer, but there are *many* differences between clients for different storage services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement their api which you want to sync (Like. dropbox, google drive).
Because their api need to apply api key and import it to your project so that their don't have one api can implement all cloud storage service.
In my experience, cloud storage api is easy to use so that you can implement it very easily.
They have tutorial so that you can implement that step by step
[Google Drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/)
[Dropbox api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers)
[Skydrive api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/live/hh826521.aspx)